# Write two variables for each loop side by side in each for loop in python

Tags: python

Dear Experts of python,

I have a code in python which has two variables rha[iz][ib] and ener[rha][iz][ib]. I want to print for each ib and for each rha, the two variables rha and ener in each line. So, rha takes a set of values rha=np.linspace(-0.02,0.02,101). And 'za' takes values like za=np.linspace(0.0,0.008,10). And 'ib' takes any number integer like 4 or 5 or 7 whatever. And ener depends on rha,za,ib, So, ener[rha,za,ib].

For example,

```
for ib = 1, 4
 for iz = 1, 10
     i should write in the output file as
            rha1, ener1
            rha2, ener2
            rha3, ener3 and so on.
```

I hope I have cleared my intention here. I cannot get the way I just described. I am getting in another way which is not useful, e.g., for each loop on ib;

```
  [rha1, rha2, rha3, rha4, 
   rha5, rha6, rha7] [ener1, ener2, ener3,
    ener4, ener5, ener6, ener7]
  [rha1, rha2, rha3, rha4,
   rha5, rha6, rha7] [ener1, ener2, ener3,
    ener4, ener5, ener6, ener7]
```

and so on.

Please suggest me something to get the output as I want.

Here is my present situation,

```py
 with open('band1.txt','w') as f:
     for iz,z in enumerate(za):
          vr=str(rha).strip('[]')
          vm=str(ener[:,iz,0]).strip('[]')
          myfile.write("%s %s\n" % (vr, vm))
```

Thank you.

Comment: Can you please clearly show your input and desired output? Your question is not clear on this at the moment.

Comment: Please provide a *complete* example, including example values of `rha` and `ener`. What about your current code doesn't work? (`vr` doesn't currently change; should that be `str(rha[iz])` rather than `str(rha)`?)

Comment: So, rha takes a set of values rha=np.linspace(-0.02,0.02,101). And 'za' takes values like za=np.linspace(0.0,0.008,10). And 'ib' takes any number integer like 4 or 5 or 7 whatever. And ener depends on rha,za,ib, So, ener[rha,za,ib]

Comment: @whoami That kind of information should be in the post itself.

Comment: Just added in the original post.